# Unable to access the BIOS Windows 7 - ASUS K8N ai Series

Tags: windows-7, boot, bios

I found an old computer that I am trying to install Linux on to. I made a bootable USB, accessed the BIOS and changed the boot section to boot from USB.

When I then restarted the computer, I was getting the error:

> reboot and select proper boot device
>
> or insert boot media in selected boot device and press a key.

I then went back into the bios and looked for the legacy boot section. I could not find a part to change between legacy and UEFI. I did find a section though to set Legacy to Auto/enable/disable.

I have changed this setting and now I cannot enter the BIOS, I have a USB keyboard and it does not register until after windows boots.

Is there anything I can do to reset the BIOS.

I was keen to update the BIOS to see if it gives me better options to then boot from USB. Can I do this and reset the bios from the windows screen?

Ive seen ways to reset the bios which involve opening up the computer, however, I would rather avoid this if possible as I wouldnt trust myself not to break it lol

Comment: In an old, BIOS PC, you won't find anything UEFI related. What you unfortunately disabled was the "Legacy USB support" that now prevents USB devices from being used before the OS takes over. An old PS2 keyboard or an adapter is what you need now to access the BIOS. That and properly prepare a bootable USB media and, of course, learn a few more details about all that because ATM you're clearly not qualified to the task.

Comment: @MichaelBay Thank you for your reply, I was looking for a PS/2 keyboard but not got one in the house. Nah im not qualified and this is a first attempt for me, which Is why I am using an old computer. If i break it then, nothing lost :-) but I have always been keen to install linux and give it a try so just a wee home project that I can hopefully replicate on my own work computer if all goes well

Comment: Not everything was lost, you learned a few things today: UEFI is what replaces BIOS in new PCs. In old PCs there's BIOS and no legacy mode which would be nonsensical since "Legacy/CSM" is there (in UEFI) to emulate the old BIOS. Also that when a USB stick doesn't boot it's because it was done incorrectly or the ISO used was corrupt (all modern distros ISOs should boot in BIOS and UEFI) and that changing USB settings can significantly affect you ability to access BIOS (with USB keyboards).

Comment: @MichaelBay Thanks again for your help. Looks like a busy night ahead trying to sort this :-) lol.

Comment: Actually "opening up the computer" is not very difficult. All you need is to disconnect the power from your PC, open the case and find a small round battery on the motherboard - like this one: http://pc-restorer.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/batteryCR2032.jpg - and just remove it and wait for 5 minutes. Then just place it back and close the case. Should reset the BIOS on old computers (and may not work on new ones).

Comment: @Evengard Thank you for your reply. most places I have seen mention a PSWD Jumper or RTCRST Jumper. If my motherboard has a battery, would it work in the same way as the Jumpers?

Comment: Most probably. Usually (especially in old computers) the BIOS data is stored in a chip which requires constant power to keep it (similar to RAM). By unplugging both the cable and the battery you remove the constant power which keeps the data on the chip, which will wipe it, and after a reboot the BIOS usually failing loading data from it just restores a default configuration.

Comment: @evengard thanks a lot. Removed the battery and sorted the problem. Easy fix :-)